# What is Weapon Handling?

Tags: borderlands-3

I don't quite understand what exactly Improved Weapon Handling does in Borderlands 3.

In Borderlands 2 and the Pre-Sequel you only had Accuracy but now you have Accuracy and Handling.

Does it reduce weapon sway? Recoil? Something else or multiple things combined?

What can I expect when using a weapon with low or high Weapon Handling respectively?

Comment: It might be something to do with how fast reticle returns to stand still size after something: after stopping moving, after switching from another weapon, after stopping fire, after getting hit, etc.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The closest thing I've found to an official statement on it, is a developer tweet:

> Handling is a single stat reflecting both recoil and gun sway. Higher numbers are better (meaning at higher numbers, the gun has less recoil and/or less sway).

What this means is that Handling will reduce the amount of sway and deviation the area gets from firing a gun (more so when firing continuously), while more Accuracy will make the initial area your gun can hit smaller.

[Source](https://twitter.com/jythri/status/1173697382866927616?s=20)

Comment: This.  It's essentially a single stat amalgamating all the little details that contribute to how well you can keep the gun on target once you fire the first round.

Comment: It's most noticable with sniper rifles -- Jakobs rifles have low handling (but high damage and bonuses for crits) ... so there's major gun sway unless you have something that improves handling